# "No route in the route table matches the supplied values." Error thrown on one view only

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I came across a strange problem in my project today: I use this action throughout my website to generate breadcrumbs for a given page:

```
@Html.Action("BreadcrumbsWithHeader2", "SharedElements", new { pageName = @Model.pageName, department = @Model.department, menuHeading = @Model.menuHeading, id = "EandTHeader" })
```

Where it just returns a PartialView. This works great on every page *except for one*, where it began throwing this error:

> No route in the route table matches the supplied values.

I've checked for things like spelling errors, etc., but am not sure how to debug this any further. What could cause something in the route table to go missing?

**Edit:** I've just noticed that any and all ActionLinks on the website pointing to this page (not the `@Html.Action` shown above, but rather the view where I call this partial) are producing blank `href` tags. The controller for it (if this helps) is here:

```
[Route("JobFair/FindAJobFair/{area}")]
public ActionResult FindAJobFair(string area, string sideMenu)
{
    ViewBag.sideMenu = sideMenu;
    JobFairsViewModel jobFairInfo = new JobFairsViewModel()
    {
        department = "Foo",
        menuHeading = null,
        pageName = "Job Fairs"
        };
    return View(jobFairInfo);
}
```

This route is typical of what I use elsewhere on the site (attribute routing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this answer helps someone in the future - the problem had to do with my variable name `area` that was passed into the controller. Since my project has an 'Areas' folder it was causing an issue with routing. I simply needed to change `area` to something like `region` and the issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Do you always provide a value for `sideMenu`? If you don't that may cause your problem. Try to modify your controller like this:

```
[Route("JobFair/FindAJobFair/{area}")]
public ActionResult FindAJobFair(string area, string sideMenu = null/*default value*/)
{
    ViewBag.sideMenu = sideMenu;
    JobFairsViewModel jobFairInfo = new JobFairsViewModel()
    {
        department = "Foo",
        menuHeading = null,
        pageName = "Job Fairs"
    };
    return View(jobFairInfo);
}
```

Comment: I do always provide a value - but just in case I provided a default value like you suggested and the error is still present.